# How to run a maven Project?

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have created java project called **OneReports**. How can i shift the entire project to Maven. Once i shifted to maven how can run in command prompt. Currently i have the problem of dependency. So i plan to move the project. Could anyone help me to step by step process.

```
C:\Jars>javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\selenium\*.jar";"OneReports.jar";"testng.jar" test\TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java

C:\Jars>java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\selenium\*.jar";"OneReports.jar";"testng.jar" test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
[[TestNGClassFinder]] Unable to read methods on class test.LoginOneReports - unable to resolve class reference org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.TestNGClassFinder.<init>(TestNGClassFinder.java:59)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.initMethods(TestRunner.java:409)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:235)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.init(TestRunner.java:205)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.<init>(TestRunner.java:153)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$DefaultTestRunnerFactory.newTestRunner(SuiteRunner.java:522)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.init(SuiteRunner.java:157)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.<init>(SuiteRunner.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunner(TestNG.java:1299)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1286)
    at org.testng.TestNG.createSuiteRunners(TestNG.java:1289)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.main(TestngTestSuiteUsingXML.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 18 more
```

C:\Jars>

Comment: Don't quote me on this, but besides being able to run from inside an IDE, I recall there is a `mvn run` (I think it's a plugin you need to enable)

Comment: The Plugin i have enabled In eclipse when i go to File->New-> other -> New wizard -> there i can see a new maven folder

Comment: If you already have eclipse with m2 plugin installed, does clicking *run* in Eclipse work?

Comment: Did you read about Maven?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You'll need to [install maven](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi).
2. Then create a [maven archetype](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html). The archetype is a base project you can add your code into.
3. Move your code. Most Maven projects follow [conventions for src, test and resource folders](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) you will want to follow when adding your code.
4. [Add your libraries](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)
5. If you add your code correctly you can [build your project](https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/index.html) using the command `mvn clean install`. This will build your project as a jar. r
6. [declare your main class](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=72602) in the pom.
7. Run the jar with the typical commands. `java -jar myJar`

This sounds like a lot of work but Maven can help immensely with managing and distributing your projects. Most professional Java developers are expected to know maven.

Comment: No... by default a maven installed jar is **not runnable**

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it correctly you want to shift your whole java project in to maven, so if yes can you please post your pom file

and for running as a maven project you should have installed apache maven, then can use  "mvn clean install test" command what this command will do , this will clean your target folder first then install all your depencies which you have given in pom file and then runs the test

Comment: Exactly you are telling but how can i get the POM file.. Is that i need to create. currently i'm using testng so i have only the test.XML file in the src folder under my java project and the test.xml looks in this structure

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" > <suite name="TestAll"> <test name="test1">
<classes> <class name="test.LoginOneReports" /> </classes>
</test> <test name="test2"> <classes> <class name="test.OEPR_DefaultTab" /> </classes> </test> <test name="test3"> classes> <class name="test.OEPR_InternalvsExternalTab" /> </classes> </test> </suite>

Comment: ok no problem folow the steps                                       1) Install the apache maven and the path in advanced variables, after 1st step is done you can check by opening the command promp and check mvn 2)then in Eclipse create a maven project where you can see pom file , open that file and add dependencies for selenium/webdriver in to that file(dependencies you will get from google just simple search if you want for selenium i have) then move your code accordingly src/main/java where you will store core java files and in src/test/java your class files

Comment: Failure to transfer org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.4.2 from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ibiblio.org has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:2.4.2 from/to ibiblio.org (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2): Access denied to http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.4.2/maven-archiver-2.4.2.jar. Error code 403, Forbidden

Comment: sory u meanu r not able to install maven , i mean when this error is coming

Comment: i created a project called test. Then the pom file has created there i'm getting error like this

Comment: i have downloaded Maven 3.2.1 from this link http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: i am not getting, this problem is coming when u run mvn clean install command, or you are not able to install apache maven.

Comment: try these links you might get an idea "http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/creating-and-running-a-simple-selenium-webdriver-test/2011-09-15"      "http://qtp-help.blogspot.in/2013/09/webdriver-with-maven.html"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48642/discussion-between-amir-and-monis-majeed)